# TypeError: Cannot set property 'jqyoui_pos' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

Getting jqyoui_pos undefined after dragging blue div on grey div.

Example code - http://plnkr.co/edit/Jk28UJ

How to fix it?

Comment: blue div is not drag-gable. Which browser you are trying?